# Attachment not sent with Email

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am developing a small E-mail app using PHP, For sending out emails I use PHPMailer, All the functionalities work apart form one "Attachments". Attachments just don't go through with the sent email. I tried many different ways to fix it but the one I have now I belief is not far off a working order....

I will post small parts of code that deal with the Attachment process....

HTML Code:

```
<form action="php/smtp_saved.php" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="attach" id="attach" />
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'Send') {

    if (preg_match('<,>', $email['recipient'])) {

        $address = explode(',', $email['recipient']);

        if (sizeof($address) < 19) {

            foreach ($address as $recipient) {

                $save = new saveSaved();
                $save->save($_SESSION['user'], $email['recipient'], gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime ('+1 hour')), $_SESSION['delete'],$email['HTML']);

                require_once('../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
                require_once('../PHPMailer/class.smtp.php');

                $mail = new PHPMailer;

                $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
                $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Specify main and backup server
                $mail->Port = '465';
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username = $_SESSION['user']; // SMTP username
                $mail->Password = $_SESSION['pass']; // SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

                $mail->From = $_SESSION['user'];
                $mail->FromName = 'OneTwoTrade';
                //$mail->addAddress($email['recipient']);  // Add a recipient
                //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');  // Name is optional
                $mail->addAddress(trim($recipient));
                if (preg_match('<,>', $email['cc'])) {

                    $cc = explode(',', $email['cc']);

                    if (sizeof($cc) < 9) {

                        foreach ($cc as $carbonC) {
                            $mail->addCC($carbonC);
                        }
                    } else {
                        exit ('Max 10 Recipients Per Email');
                    }

                } else {
                    $mail->addCC($email['cc']);
                }
                //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

                $mail->WordWrap = 50; // Set word wrap to 50 characters

                if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'])) {
                    $file = $_FILES['attach']['name'];
                    $mail->AddAttachment($file);

                }


                /*
                if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&  $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

                    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                                         $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

                }
*/
                        // Add attachments



                //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
                $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

                $mail->Subject = $email['subject'];
                $mail->Body = $email['HTML'];
                //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
                //$mail->SMTPDebug =1;
                if (!$mail->send()) {
                    header("Location: ../saved_emails.php?error2");
                    //echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                    //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me to spot a mistake or direct to a decent source of information....?

Comment: Thank you I have tried this but makes no difference, still sends emails without attachments, Maybe I have to specyfie the file extension or Size...?

Comment: can you post all code you have for this operation? I have to see what is going on before talking

Comment: ok I added the whole PHP Mailer class have look

Comment: when i var_dump these: `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'])) {
                    $file = $_FILES['attach']['name']` I get this: bool(true) string(12) "IMG_0669.JPG" so everything looks gd but still nothing is send....

Answer (score 1):

When attaching a file via a form add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the `form` tag. I think the problem occurs because of this.

```
<form action="php/smtp_saved.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="attach" id="attach" />
</form>
```

After a little search, I have found this: Both `temp_name` and `name` keys for the attached file are used in `AddAttachment()` function:

```
if(isset($_FILES['attach']) && $_FILES['attach']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['attach']['name']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I have tried this but makes no difference, still sends emails without attachments, Maybe I have to specyfie the file extension or Size...?

Comment: Ye I though of this and I addatched a file that is 1bit in size and still not sending then i guess there is more to it

Answer (score 1):

`$file = $_FILES['attach']['name'];` should be `$file = $_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'];`. The actual file data is in `$_FILES['attach']['tmp_name']`. `$_FILES['attach']['name']` is just the name given to the uploaded file on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys Want to thx all of you who tried to help me and pushed me to the solution, I managed to fix it this is what I had to do...

```
 if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'])) {
                $file = $_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'];
                $name = $_FILES['attach']['name'];
                $mail->AddAttachment($file, $name);

            }
```

:)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Works like a charm, just checked the PHPMailer Documentation and the AddAttachment Method needs two parameters,